# Mongoose await doc.save() Incomplete

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I fetch a JSON object from a remote server successfully. The JSON file is an array of objects. I loop over them and during the loop I try to save each document object with mongoose as below. But only 50 records are saved out of 500. So obviously I am doing something wrong with async/await. Your help is appreciated.

*Edit: Added more of the code upon request from users.*

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const fetch = require('fetch-json')
const PriceModel = mongoose.model('Price', priceSchema);

getPrices = async () => {
  try {
    const url = 'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price'
    const params = ''
    const jsonData = await fetch.get(url, params)
    return jsonData

  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Error caught during getPrices: ', e.message)
  }
}

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/prices', { useNewUrlParser: true });

const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function () {
  console.log('we\'re connected')
});

const priceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  timestamp: Date,
  symbol: String,
  price: Number
});

    persistData = async () => {

      try {
        const timestamp = Date.now()
        const allPrices = await getPrices()

        for (const element of allPrices) {
          let doc = new PriceModel()
          doc.timestamp = timestamp
          doc.symbol = element.symbol
          doc.price = element.price
          await doc.save()
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log('Error caught during db save: ', e.message)
      }
    }
```

Comment: Your code is valid here, correct async/await usage, looping... Are you sure that the `allPrices` length is 500? Could you share more context? Schema, mongoose settings, etc.?

Comment: Click on the url you will see the size of the JSON data. No way it's 50 docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As from version 4.4 mongoose does support [insertMany](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.insertMany) operation. So a much faster algorithm will be to prepare your needed data:

```
const priceModels = [];

for (const element of allPrices) {
  let doc = {
     timestamp,
     ...element,
  }
  priceModels.push(doc)
}
```

And after you prepared all the objects, you make one insert to the database:

```
await PriceModel.insertMany(priceModels);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I can't believe my eyes that I finally got an answer in stack overflow without anyone mentioning it's a duplicate. Thank's a lot. Will try it now!

Comment: I've reread the documentation, and it seems, insertMany accepts raw objects, even better for your case.

Comment: notice: I understand your concern about the timestamp but I put it there intentionally because I want all the items to take the same timestamp. Contrary to "normal".

Comment: do you mean that I do not need a for loop?

Comment: I mean you don't need to make a separate insert request for every object, you can create a single db request with all the docs, and this will be much faster.

Comment: I tried it and it works. But I still get 50 documents. I think the fetch-json api I am using is malfunctioning, I will try to use the original node-fetch api and see what happens. If you want to verify, the link of the api is up, it's obviously more than 50 documents.

Comment: console.log(arrayOfItems.length)
await PriceModel.insertMany(arrayOfItems);
Output>>
we're connected
510

Comment: The array length is 500. The documents produced 50!

Comment: Ok, I think it might be related to the Schema. Although I put it Number, I still see scientific notation as the output in my collections proposing that perhaps the "invalid" numbers are left out.

Comment: Before inserting mongoose, validate all the objects, and it seems you are trying to insert some invalid objects. Use strict false for debugging to see what data you receive https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts Alexandru. I gave you best answer because yours was the best answer and also the most helpful user. It turns out that the reason I receive only 50 documents is because Robo3T displays only 50 documents in one page, but also it starts counting from 1 on each page. I still have some problems with the price key as the numbers are converted to scientific notation. Thanks for your help!